# Application works well on emulator but it crashes when run on the phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-asynctask

I'm writing an application that one of the function is to update a user profile in an external sql database from the android device. So I'm sending a request to update.php file using a Background Async task thread. Application works fine on emulator 2.3.3 and it successfully updates the profile in a database but when I try to run it on a tablet or a phone with android 4.0.3 it takes a long time until ProgressDialog defined in onPreExecute() dismisses and it gives me an error. Here is a stack:

```
08-12 08:46:14.303: E/Buffer Error(3167): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
08-12 08:46:14.303: D/Update Response(3167): {"student":[{"understandPref":"0","genderPref":"Male","username":"ma","secondLangPref":"none","bilingualismPref":"no","ethnicPref":"American","lichPref":"0","pobPref":"Argentina","password":"fd","speakPref":"0","domLangPref":"US\/English","agePref":"15"}],"success":1}
08-12 08:46:14.303: D/AndroidRuntime(3167): Shutting down VM
08-12 08:46:14.303: W/dalvikvm(3167): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409e21f8)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:587)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:324)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:151)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:328)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:119)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:313)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at edu.neiu.voiceofchicago.activities.SettingsActivity$UpdateAccount.onPostExecute(SettingsActivity.java:519)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at edu.neiu.voiceofchicago.activities.SettingsActivity$UpdateAccount.onPostExecute(SettingsActivity.java:1)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-12 08:46:14.323: E/AndroidRuntime(3167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why it works on emulator and it does not on the phone? Please advise. Thanks.

JSONParser.class

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) throws IOException {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();


        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

> 08-12 08:46:14.303: E/Buffer Error(3167): Error converting result
>   java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.

Put your reading from stream part in try catch block . Most probably the connection you made to the php file closed .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it still doesn't work. I have attached the whole class.